# REACT state update with loop overrides previous values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, state

I have this simple function to update the state in React.
It takes a simple URL from URLs array then fetch additional data and create newItem
It should update Another state which is also array with this new object.
But it override first item with every another.
Why its like that ?

````
for (const item of urls) {
  const url = item.url
  const ID = url.slice((url.search("=",0) + 1), url.length)
  const YtResponse = GetByIdYouTube(ID)
  const data = await YtResponse
  const date = item.date
  const newItem = {data, url, date}
  setDisplay(display.concat(newItem))
}

}; ```
````

Answer (score 2):

`SetDisplay` is an asynchronous function. try to call it outside the for loop. Make a separate array while iterating, and append that array to the previously maintained `display` state after for loop.

```
separateArray = []
for (const item of urls) {
  const url = item.url
  const ID = url.slice((url.search("=",0) + 1), url.length)
  const YtResponse = GetByIdYouTube(ID)
  const data = await YtResponse
  const date = item.date
  const newItem = {data, url, date}
  separateArray.push(newItem)
}    

setDisplay([...display, ...separateArray])
```

Comment: Thanks, i try this solution but in that form above it don't have access to a separate array so i add a return statement in the loop but then it don't do anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the previous state :

```
setDisplay({ (display) => { display.concat(newItem) }})
```

Or there is also this solution :

```
const t = display.concat(newItem)
setDisplay(t)
```

Comment: thanks but it still does the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected

```
for (const item of urls) {
      const url = item.url;
      const ID = url.slice(url.search("=", 0) + 1, url.length);
      const YtResponse = GetByIdYouTube(ID);
      const data = await YtResponse;
      const date = item.date;
      const newItem = { data, url, date };
      let temp = [...display]; // Make a copy of array then update state
      temp.push(newItem);
      setDisplay(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I found a half solution :) this function should have the ability to add one or multiple values.
Now with the code below it works when it reads multiple values at once from the initial state (URLs state)
But when I update Urls state by add one value and useEffect triggers this func
its fails it seems to structure of data is not array any more

````
   const newArr = []
  for (const item of urls) {
    const url = item.url;
    const ID = url.slice(url.search("=", 0) + 1, url.length);
    const YtResponse = GetByIdYouTube(ID);
    const data = await YtResponse;
    const date = item.date;
    const newItem = { data, url, date };
    newArr.push(newItem)
}
  setDisplay(...display, newArr) 

 };```
````